# jquery ui checkbox button state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I have a group of checkbox buttons, what is the correct way to determine the button state?

Right now I do this:

```
$('#group label').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-pressed') == 'true') {
        /* Do something */
    }
});
```

But sometimes no checkbox buttons are checked and some still have `aria-pressed = true`.  I don't understand it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` on the jQuery object containing your checkbox to test if it's checked.